# I can't get php session forwarded to another page

Tags: php, session

My code has a login page with two different users Admin and user
login page:
[image]

The menu options for admin and user differ. They have options in common also
Admin page After Login
[image]

User login
[image]

Now here for user and Admin i'm creating two different files like aboutus.php,aboutus1.php which only have different menu options. Now here i want create two php files like menu1.php and menu2.php and include it to all the pages based on login session. But i'm not getting the session variable carried to other pages.

Comment: are you doing session_start() before trying to use $_SESSION?

Comment: You might also want to include some code along with your question.

Comment: Pls post some code in much way of assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you start sessions on all pages you redirect to

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Or start it in file (f.e. config.php holding all variables) and than include it on every page to carry the session parameters over.

Regards.

Comment: should i add it in each and every page

Comment: yes on start of every page just include on the top session_start or create a header file and add session_start and then include that header in all your pages

Comment: Yes, where ever you want session to be carried to.

Comment: I got an error including session start in every file, you're better of using if(!isset($_SESSION){session_start();}

Answer (score 0):

You should use `session_start();` in your home page, on the other pages, use

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION){ session_start();}?>
```

If you use `session_start();` on each individual page, you will receive an error regarding running multiple sessions, atleast thats what I had.